# getting ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection when running pl/sql block for extracting json array

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

Im trying to run the below code and im getting ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection error. I tried initializint the collection. But still im getting the error.

```
DECLARE
    V_JDOC_ARRAY   JSON_ARRAY_T;
    V_TEST2UUIDS   JSON_OBJECT_T;
    V_KEYS         JSON_KEY_LIST;
    v_cnt          NUMBER;
BEGIN
    V_JDOC_ARRAY := JSON_ARRAY_T ('[
                                    {
                                     "test1UUIDs": {},
                                     "test2UUIDs": {
                                                    "1": "aaaaaa",
                                                    "2": "bbbbb"
                                                   }
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "test1UUIDs": {},
                                     "test2UUIDs": {}
                                    }
                                  ]');

    FOR V_I IN 0 .. V_JDOC_ARRAY.GET_SIZE - 1
    LOOP
        V_TEST2UUIDS :=
            TREAT (
                TREAT (V_JDOC_ARRAY.GET (V_I) AS JSON_OBJECT_T).GET (
                    'test2UUIDs')
                    AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
        V_KEYS := V_TEST2UUIDS.GET_KEYS;
        v_cnt := V_KEYS.COUNT; **--where error is occuring**
        --V_KEYS := JSON_KEY_LIST ();
    --FOR V_J IN 1..V_KEYS.COUNT LOOP
    --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST2UUIDS(' || (V_I + 1) || '): ' || V_KEYS(V_J) || ' ' || V_TEST2UUIDS.GET_STRING(V_KEYS(V_J)));
    --END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Need a solution to over come this

Comment: Your code works in [Oracle 21](https://dbfiddle.uk/CWHqtm_x) it fails in [Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/x4Pxylk6).

Comment: Will this work in 19c?

Comment: I do not have access to an Oracle 19 instance to test it on; however, I'm assuming from the previous comment that you are using Oracle 19 and you get the error and if that is the case then you have answered your own comment and, no, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a change in the behaviour somewhere between Oracle 18 and Oracle 21.

- In Oracle 18, if there are no keys then `NULL` is returned (rather than a collection).
- In Oracle 21, if there are no keys then an empty collection is returned.

---

To fix it in earlier versions, add a check to see of the collection is `NULL`:

```sql
DECLARE
  V_JDOC_ARRAY   JSON_ARRAY_T;
  V_TEST2UUIDS   JSON_OBJECT_T;
  V_KEYS         JSON_KEY_LIST;
  v_cnt          NUMBER;
BEGIN
  V_JDOC_ARRAY := JSON_ARRAY_T ('[
                                  {
                                   "test1UUIDs": {},
                                   "test2UUIDs": {
                                                  "1": "aaaaaa",
                                                  "2": "bbbbb"
                                                 }
                                  },
                                  {
                                   "test1UUIDs": {},
                                   "test2UUIDs": {}
                                  }
                                ]');

  FOR V_I IN 0 .. V_JDOC_ARRAY.GET_SIZE - 1
  LOOP
    V_TEST2UUIDS := TREAT(
      TREAT(V_JDOC_ARRAY.GET (V_I) AS JSON_OBJECT_T)
        .GET('test2UUIDs')
      AS JSON_OBJECT_T
    );
    V_KEYS := V_TEST2UUIDS.GET_KEYS();
    IF v_keys IS NOT NULL THEN
      FOR V_J IN 1..V_KEYS.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
          'TEST2UUIDS(' || (V_I + 1) || '): ' || V_KEYS(V_J) || ' ' || V_TEST2UUIDS.GET_STRING(V_KEYS(V_J))
        );
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Another alternative is to use `COALESCE` when getting the keys to ensure that if `NULL` is returned then an empty collection is substituted in its place:

```sql
V_KEYS := COALESCE(V_TEST2UUIDS.GET_KEYS(), JSON_KEY_LIST());
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aNFGKSOO)